# How can i add oncomplete evetn to movie clip generated from animate CC exporter

Tags: createjs, animate-cc, tweenjs

i have a canvas project created by Animate CC , 
i need to add "onComplete" event to a movie clip generated from Animate CC canvas project , 
the solution present from createjs site :

```
target.alpha = 1;
createjs.Tween.get(target)
     .wait(500)
     .to({alpha:0, visible:false}, 1000)
     .call(handleComplete);
function handleComplete() {
    //Tween complete
}
```

[from tweenJs site](http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html)

i don't want to modify the js file generated by Animate CC , but i could not find a way to hock to movie clip tween 
I've tried to access exportRoot.MyMovieClipInstanceName.timeline to get the tween but with not lock

regards

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to access the timeline directly -- MovieClips fire a "animationend" event when their timeline is complete. From *anywhere* you should be able to do:

```
exportRoot.instance.on("animationend", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

You could also add code to the timeline in Animate, which basically does the same thing.

```
this.on("animationend", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your time , it didn't work  both solutions

Comment: I would have to see the setup to provide any more details. Can you post a sample somewhere?